# videogular vg-scrub-bar on android mobile device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, videogular

I am using videogular in my ionic project and there is a strange kind of error by using the vg-scrub-bar.

I always got the following error-message in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'currentTime' property on
>   'HTMLMediaElement': The provided double value is non-finite.

Only on Android-Phones, on all other devices and in the webbrowser it works fine.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This commit solves it](https://github.com/videogular/videogular/commit/5e7de4290de08637d5cc8d3adc34f758ff74918a)

However in the latest release 1.4.4 it still doesn't seem to work on Galaxy tablet, although scrub bar now scrubs properly if you tap it anywhere (touch start), but still doesn't work properly on move.

But by applying the aforementioned commit to a 1.2.8 version it works. Hope it helps you.